# Pyplot hist sum of bin counts is not equal to number of elements

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using pyplot to plot histogram, and found that the sum of bin counts is not equal to the total sum of elements. Where could be possible errors here?

```
data = [1.272499, 1.3480160000000001, 1.42106, 1.431921, 0.95531699999999997, 1.167071, 1.2155849999999999, 0.716526, 1.356554]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(np.array(data), bins = np.arange(-0.2,1.6,0.2))
assert np.sum(n) == len(data)
```

Here n are:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  4.]
7 9
```

Comment: Nvm, I assigned range of the bins to be too small.

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not see that you have already found the error before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest histogram bin ends at 1.4, so the two values higher than 1.4 are not included. You should use `np.arange(-0.2, 1.8, 0.2)` instead. This produces the array `[-0.2  0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.   1.2  1.4  1.6]`, and your assertion will be `True`.